# subtract two binary images with different coordinates

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have two binary images which is to be subtracted in order to get the result image.

The two images are of different size so I aligned them using image registration method, but do not know

- **how to find the coordinates of the matching part of image and subtract them**
- or is there **any other method to subtract images**?

Comment: Share with us your code? What you got so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is good, you almost finish the work. After registration, you just need to detect which one of the two images have the lowest and highest X and Y coordinates.

If your registration give you the translation, with the width and height of your two images you can compute the 4 values you need (Xmin, Xmax, Ymin, Ymax).

I put a picture in order to be little more clear :
[image]

Comment: thanks a bunch..it is a valuable suggestion..my new coordinates are [Xmin=7,Xmax=309] and [Ymin=9,Ymax=234]...but I am  bit confused about subtraction...how to do it..Image A is of size 240*320 and Image B is of size 230*310...

Comment: The size of the images is used for computing Xmin, Xmax, Ymin Ymax.
Xmin will be the biggest value between XAmin and XBmin and Xmax will be the smallest value between XAmax and XBmax. So the starting point of the image will be Xmin and the ending point will be Xmax. The width will be Xmax-Xmin